# How to get the number of child nodes using XPath for HTML?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a the following structure within html:

```html
<A>
   <b>1</b>
   <b>2</b>
   <b>3</b>
</A>
```

How I can select the count of child nodes A using C# and webdriver?

Comment: Is the third bold element purposefully mangled?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have removed the snippet, since there's nothing to run. We also agreed to remove "Thanks in advance" or "Best regards" statements, since they are not helpful to describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works...

Program.cs:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;


namespace SeleniumTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file://" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\", "/") + "test.html");
                //Use this line to capture all child "b" elements
                var bElements = driver.FindElementByXPath("//A").FindElements(By.TagName("b"));
                //Use the line below to capture all descendants
                var bElements2 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//A").FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));
                //Use the line below to capture all immediate child elements
                var bElements3 = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//A/*");

                Console.WriteLine("Child elements1: " + bElements.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Child elements2: " + bElements2.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Child elements3: " + bElements3.Count);

                driver.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <A>
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
        <b>3
            <c>4</c>
        </b>
        <z>5</z>
    </A>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Child elements1: 3
Child elements2: 5
Child elements3: 4
```

Comment: The OP asked for "child nodes [of] A". I think it would be more correct to say: `driver.FindElements(By.XPath"//A/*")`? Your commented version, `By.XPath(".//*")`, will find not only child elements, but also *their* children if any.

Comment: HTML, XHTML, ... sometimes a single letter can make a huge difference. Not sure that would work for HTML.

Comment: @SiKing Thanks for your input. I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.